# Polygon to Raster is creating a blank surface

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am attempting to create a raster surface that has values of 1 where my polygons of historical fires are and then 0 for areas of no data. I created a field that just gives every polygon a value of 1 and tried using it as the burn in value but this just created a blank surface. I wanted to make a 30m by 30m raster of these polygons. The starting vector layer is in WGS 84 EPSG:4326

This is the code that is created from the settings I tried to use with the Rasterize (Vector to Raster) tool.

```
processing.run("gdal:rasterize", {'INPUT':'C:/Users/dantd/Documents/School Stuff/Geog 422/Historical_Fire_Clip_extrafield.shp','FIELD':'Fire_Exist','BURN':1,'USE_Z':False,'UNITS':1,'WIDTH':30,'HEIGHT':30,'EXTENT':None,'NODATA':0,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':5,'INIT':None,'INVERT':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image: The settings I used]

Comment: You're trying to create a 30x30 decimal degree pixel, not 30x30 metre. Reproject your vector to a projected not geographic CRS.

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks alot. used EPSG:3157 and it worked perfectly.